# "Double headed" vector

Tags: macros, arrows, vector

I want to have a double headed vector. I tried `\overleftright`, but the appearance is all but pretty. I would like to get the same kind of symbol, but with `\vec` appearance. Is it possible?

Comment: `\overrightarrow`. `\overleftarrow`.  <-- mentioned to improve search results...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Built using stacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\vecsign{\mathchar"017E}
\def\dvecsign{\smash{\stackon[-1.95pt]{\vecsign}{\rotatebox{180}{$\vecsign$}}}}
\def\dvec#1{\def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2pt]{#1}{\,\dvecsign}}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$ \vec c \vec A  \dvec c \dvec A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

There remains a slight possibility for overlap, when, for example, having `$\dvec d \dvec b$`.  That issue can be remedied by using a little kern to make a narrower `\dvec`, as follows.  To recover the original, reset `\shrinkage` to `0mu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\shrinkage{2.1mu}
\def\vecsign{\mathchar"017E}
\def\dvecsign{\smash{\stackon[-1.95pt]{\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign}{\rotatebox{180}{$\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign$}}}}
\def\dvec#1{\def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2pt]{#1}{\,\dvecsign}}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$ \vec c \vec A  \dvec c \dvec A$
$\dvec d \dvec b $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because of my font election, I had to change -1.95 for -2.60, but your answer is abusuletly brilliant and elegant.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández  Note that I added a `\smash` to `\dvecsign` else it had too much dead space above it.

Comment: Just wondering, is this possible to accomplish via `\newcommand` instead of `\def`?

Comment: Yes.  For `\shrinkage`, `\vecsign` and `\dvecsign`, merely substituting `\newcommand` for `\def` will suffice.  For the case of `\dvec`, substitute `\newcommand\dvec[1]` for `\def\dvec#1`. The differences between `\def` and `\newcommand`, outside of the syntax, is that `\newcommand` arguments can have `\par`s in them, whereas `\def` cannot, unless you define it `\long`.  Also, `\newcommand` will only proceed, if the command name does not already exist, whereas `\def` will overwrite an existing macro.  And, of course, `\newcommand` can take optional arguments conveniently.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I usually use `\newcommand` (just simple things, though). That worked nicely.

Comment: Like @AlfredoHernández I had to change the `\stackon[-1.95]` to `\stackon[-2.35pt]` to have the arrows overlap, apart from that nice solution! (would be nice to have an explanation on which numbers do what)