# Typesetting arrows above a pair of letters to indicate a line

Tags: math-mode, arrows, accents

How do I typeset a line segment, with arrowheads at each end, above a pair of letters to indicate a line?  I know that `$\overline{AB}$` can be used to typeset a line segment between points `A` and `B`.  How do I draw an arrow above a pair of letters to indicate a ray?

Comment: `\overleftrightarrow{}` from `amsmath` package.

Comment: `\overleftrightarrow{AB}`, more precisely.

Comment: @Sigur and  Gustavo Mezzetti  Thanks for the command.  I am looking to put an arrow above two letters.  This will be just fine.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti  Does `\overrightarrow{}` give me the symbol for a ray?

Comment: Of course, `\overrightarrow{AB}` typesets “AB” with an arrow pointing rightward above the two letters; but you asked for a segment “with arrowheads at each end“, didn’t you? :-)

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti  I also had asked "How do I draw an arrow above a pair of letters to indicate a ray?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments have already mentioned `\overleftrightarrow`.  Here is an alternative that tries to make the segment use the same heads as `\vec`, also shown for comparison.

Based on my answer at ["Double headed" vector](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162337/double-headed-vector/162342#162342), except that I had to make it extensible to match segments of different sizes.

On the left are two `\vec`s, two `\dvec`s and on the right are two `\overleftrightarrow`s.  Below is a very wide `\dvec`.

EDITED, based on Leon's suggestion, to improve the height of the `\dvec`, so as to be compatible with `\vec` when using `\left...\right` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\shrinkage{-2.4mu}
\def\vecsign#1{\rule[1.388\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.36\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
\def\dvecsign#1{\rule{0pt}{7\LMpt}\smash{\stackon[-1.989\LMpt]{%
  \SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}}%
  {\rotatebox{180}{$\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}$}}}}
\def\dvec#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\dvecsign{\wd0}}}}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$ \vec c ~\vec A  ~\dvec{ac} ~\dvec{AB} ~\textrm{vs.}
  ~\overleftrightarrow{ac} ~\overleftrightarrow{AB}$

$\dvec{ABCD} ~\scriptstyle \dvec A ~\dvec{AB}~\scriptscriptstyle \dvec A ~\dvec{AB}$

$
\left(\dvec{A}\right)\left(\vec{A}\right)
\scriptstyle\left(\dvec{A}\right)\left(\vec{A}\right)
\scriptscriptstyle\left(\dvec{A}\right)\left(\vec{A}\right)
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Based on the OP's request, I provide `\ray{}` below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\shrinkage{-2.4mu}
\def\vecsign#1{\rule[1.388\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.36\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
\def\dvecsign#1{\rule{0pt}{7\LMpt}\smash{\stackon[-1.989\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}}%
  {\rotatebox{180}{$\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}$}}}}
\def\dvec#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\dvecsign{\wd0}}}}
\def\theraysign#1{\rule{0pt}{17\LMpt}\rule[1.384\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.40\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
\def\raysign#1{\rule{0pt}{7\LMpt}\smash{%
  \SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\theraysign{#1}}}
\def\ray#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\raysign{\wd0}}}}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$ \vec c ~\vec A  ~\ray{ac} ~\ray{AB} ~\textrm{vs.}
  ~\overleftrightarrow{ac} ~\overleftrightarrow{AB}$

$\ray{ABCD} ~\scriptstyle \ray A ~\ray{AB}~\scriptscriptstyle \ray A ~\ray{AB}$

$
\left(\ray{AB}\right)\left(\vec{AB}\right)
\scriptstyle\left(\ray{AB}\right)\left(\vec{AB}\right)
\scriptscriptstyle\left(\ray{AB}\right)\left(\vec{AB}\right)
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the small arrow head is much much better than the default one. Very nice!

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes  I agree with Sigur - the arrowheads on the default arrows are too big.  I plan to put arrows, with arrowheads at both ends to indicate a line, and with arrowheads at the right end to indicate a ray.  I don't know anything about your code in the preamble.  Please give me the code that I need to put in the preamble for lines and rays.  (I will put arrows only above a pair of letters.)

Comment: @user74973 I have provided an addendum with `\ray`.  As far as the preamble, I have provided everything you need.  The `\ray` does have a square left end, rather than rounded.  If this is an issue, let me know.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes  Thanks for including the code for typesetting rays.  Looks nice!

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes  I am (almost) sure that I will be typesetting arrows, with arrowheads at both ends of a line segment or only at the right end of a line segment, over a pair of capital letters.  Please tell me which commands that you have in your preamble are pertinent to what I need.

Comment: @user74973  In the ADDENDUM code, everything between `\usepackage{scalerel}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}` (including those lines) should be copied into your preamble, which will allow the use of `\dvec` and `\ray`.  Note that the measurements and alignment are calibrated for the Computer-Modern font, and will need tweaking if you wish to employ this approach for other fonts.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes  I am using the font included with `amsart`.

Comment: @user74973 The code using `amsart`works just fine, I just verified, unless you employ additional font modifications after using `amsart`.  For example, `\usepackage{txfonts}` will require a rework, for example.

Comment: @LeonMeier To fix the `\left` issue (I think), one can add a `\rule{0pt}{7pt}` just prior to the smash` in the definition of `\dvecsign`.  As to the nitpick.  Any overlaid glyph arrangement will be subject to the vagaries of the rendering software at lower resolutions, because of the feature called "hinting" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting)

Comment: @LeonMeier You are right.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @LeonMeier That problem is not wholly unexpected.  It is neither a hinting issue nor a rendering issue. It arises from the fact that a `\Huge` letter is not merely a scaled up version of the normal-sized letter, just as a `\tiny` letter is not merely a scaled down version of the normal-sized letter.  What this means is that the relative proportions of the letters have changed, and so the amount of adjustment that is needed for my custom-fitted algorithms needs to change (basically for each font-size and certainly so if the actual font is changed).  This is the essential drawback of my approach