# Arrows over letter in LaTeX file indicating a ray is not drawn correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

I am adopting code for drawing arrows above letters indicating rays from Steven B. Segletes; he had replied to a post "Typesetting arrows above a pair of letters to indicate a line" on tex.stackexchange.com. When I changed the font to `\footnotesize`, the arrow seems to have a dash typed in front of the arrowhead. How do I get the arrow drawn correctly - and longer? Currently, the arrowheads of the arrows are drawn directly over the letters "r," "s," and "t."

Is it customary to have the prime typeset under the arrow or beside it when the ray is indicated by a single letter?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



  \usepackage{scalerel}
  \def\shrinkage{-2.4mu}
  \def\vecsign#1{\rule[1.388\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.36\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
  \def\dvecsign#1{\smash{\stackon[-1.989\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}}%
  {\rotatebox{180}{$\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}$}}}}
  \def\dvec#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\dvecsign{\wd0}}}}
  \def\theraysign#1{\rule[1.384\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.40\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
  \def\raysign#1{\smash{\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\theraysign{#1}}}
  \def\ray#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\raysign{\wd0}}}}
  \usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
  \stackMath
  \usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%An angle and its angle bisector are drawn.

\path (0,0) coordinate (A');
\path ($(A') +({(3/11)*(10)},0)$) coordinate (O') ($(O') +({(3/11)*9*(3/5)},{(3/11)*9*(4/5)})$) coordinate (B');
\node[anchor={180-1/2*(acos(-3/5))}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(O') +({(180-1/2*(acos(-3/5)))+180}:0.1)$){$O{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}$};
\draw[-latex] (O') -- ($(A')!-0.75cm!(O')$);
\path node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A')!-0.85cm!(O')$){$\ray{r{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$};
\draw[-latex] (O') -- ($(B')!-0.75cm!(O')$);
\path node[anchor={(180-acos(-3/5))+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B')!-0.75cm!(O')$){$\ray{s{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$};



\coordinate (C') at ($(O') +({(3/11)*(-36/19)},{(3/11)*72/19})$);
\draw[-latex, dashed] (O') -- ($(C')!-1cm!(O')$);
\path node[anchor={(180-1/2*(acos(-3/5)))+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(C')!-1cm!(O')$)!-0.05cm!(O')$){$\ray{t{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that this question is not tagged correctly as the problem with the arrows should also occur if used outside of the Ti*k*Z context and therefore is independent of Ti*k*Z. You should probably reduce your MWE to contain only the essential parts to make it easier to grasp what you are actually asking. But why don't you just use `$\vec{s}'$` or maybe `$\vec{s}\kern2mu'$` to have a better spacing? The idea of the [answer you cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254172/47927) was to place an arrow over *two* letters, but you only need to place it over single letters it seems.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  As my sample was only that of a `TikZ` diagram, I tagged it as that. As the typesetting only occurs within the nodes of the `TikZ` diagram, it would be appropriate to tag `tex.core`.

Comment: I agree with Jasper.  Just because you use code within TikZ, that doesn't mean TikZ is needed for your question (the code in the answer you cite isn't in TikZ, for example).  Double check the [tag:tex-core] page: being within TikZ would be the opposite of tex.core, as would using any packages.  And again: why not `$\vec{s}'$`?

Answer (score 3):

The code you've borrowed is for an arrow that can be as long as necessary.  Since you only need one letter, I don't quite see why you want that code.  The following is four different ways of typesetting the four labels you have in your code.  (I've taken the labels out of the TikZ picture, since that was unrelated to what you're trying to do.)

1. Your approach, where the arrows are too close to their letters in footnote size.
2. The TeX defined `\vec`, where the prime is too close to the vector.
3. `\vec`, but then using Jasper's suggested `\mkern2mu`.
4. Using `\,`, which TeX defines to be `\mkern3mu`.

Options 3 and 4 look good to me.  Note that the preamble is only present for option 1; options 2, 3, and 4 require no preamble at all.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% this entire preample is only necessary for defining \ray
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\shrinkage{-2.4mu}
\def\vecsign#1{\rule[1.388\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.36\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
\def\dvecsign#1{\smash{\stackon[-1.989\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}}%
  {\rotatebox{180}{$\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\vecsign{#1}$}}}}
\def\dvec#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\dvecsign{\wd0}}}}
\def\theraysign#1{\rule[1.384\LMex]{\dimexpr#1-2.5pt}{.40\LMpt}%
  \kern-6.0\LMpt\mathchar"017E}
\def\raysign#1{\smash{\SavedStyle\mkern-\shrinkage\theraysign{#1}}}
\def\ray#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackon[-4.2\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\,\raysign{\wd0}}}}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline
& Normal size & Footnote size\\\hline
your approach
& $O{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}$, $\ray{r{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$, $\ray{s{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$, $\ray{t{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$
& {\footnotesize $O{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}$, $\ray{r{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$, $\ray{s{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$, $\ray{t{\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{${}^{\prime}$}}}}$} \\
naive approach
& $O'$, $\vec r'$, $\vec s'$, $\vec t'$
& {\footnotesize $O'$, $\vec r'$, $\vec s'$, $\vec t'$} \\
Jasper's suggested kern
& $O'$, $\vec r\mkern2mu'$, $\vec s\mkern2mu'$, $\vec t\mkern2mu'$
& {\footnotesize $O'$, $\vec r\mkern2mu'$, $\vec s\mkern2mu'$, $\vec t\mkern2mu'$} \\
thinmuskip
& $O'$, $\vec r\,'$, $\vec s\,'$, $\vec t\,'$
& {\footnotesize $O'$, $\vec r\,'$, $\vec s\,'$, $\vec t\,'$} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: As Steven B. Segletes stated in the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114321/extensible-vec-instead-of-overrightarrow,  "`\vec` does not always put the arrow where I want it."  I also do not like how short the arrow is using `\vec`.

Comment: Using `\normalsize` font, I like the height and length of the arrow with the code that I provided. I don't like the height of the arrow when I use `\footnotesize` font.

Comment: What would you suggest to increase the height of the arrows so that I can use `\footnotesize` font?

Comment: @user74973 I assume by height you mean the vertical placement of the arrow. Probably something like $\vec{\vphantom{t}r}$.  A more manual placement would involve `\raisebox`.